# Have I set up server emails correctly with Google SPF?

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, spf

Good Morning
I am having a bit of trouble getting SPF Pass on mail headers when emails are sent through Contact Form 7 on Wordpress.

Mail sent through Contact From 7 often goes to spam and when looking at the Mail Source Headers, I can see the site IP doesn't designate as a permitted sender.

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   spf=neutral (google.com: *serverIP* is neither permitted nor denied by 
best guess record for domain of www-data@ubuntu) smtp.mailfrom=www-data@ubuntu;
   dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=*domain*
Return-Path: <www-data@ubuntu>
Received: from ubuntu (*domain*. [*serverIP*])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTP id 91-v6si4638670wre.46.2018.05.17.07.10.20;
    Thu, 17 May 2018 07:10:20 -0700 (PDT)
 Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: *serverIP* is neither permitted nor 
denied by best guess record for domain of www-data@ubuntu) client- 
ip=*ServerIP*;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=neutral (google.com: *ServerIP* is neither permitted nor denied by 
best guess record for domain of www-data@ubuntu) smtp.mailfrom=www- 
data@ubuntu;
   dmarc=fail (p=NONE sp=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=*Domain*
Received: by ubuntu (Postfix, from userid 33)
id 036C93F7D3; Thu, 17 May 2018 14:10:20 +0000 (UTC)
```

SPF records have all been set up in DNS settings and are correct when checked by Google's SPF testing tool
We are using Google Business Apps. Everything is fine with DKIM, DMARC and SPF so not sure why it saying SPF Neutral and DMARC fail...

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is the problem:

```
Return-Path: <www-data@ubuntu>
```

The return-path header is added by the receiving server (google), and is not something that you should set as a sender. The receiving server sets it from the SMTP `MAIL FROM` address, also known as an "envelope sender". This address is also where bounces should be sent, not the from or reply-to addresses specified *within* the message.

The problem here is that in the absence of an explicitly set envelope sender, PHP tries to guess one by looking up the current user and host name that are running the submitting process. This is why your envelope sender is `www-data` (the user name) @ `ubuntu` (the host name of your server). `ubuntu` is not a resolvable host name, so google can't look up an SPF record to check it against, so it falls back to the default "neutral" SPF verdict, which is what you're seeing.

There are a few ways to deal with this. First of all you should set the hostname of your server so it knows what to call itself - PHP will see that info and use it to set the fallback address. If you run the `hostname` command, you'll probably get `ubuntu`, so fix that (both immediately and permanently) by running:

```
sudo hostname myhostname.example.com
echo "myhostname.example.com" | sudo tee /etc/hostname
```

substitute your real host and domain name of course.

Setting the user name is trickier, but is not actually necessary to get an SPF pass, because that only looks at the domain, so `www-data@myhostname.example.com` will work fine, though you may run into issues if you want to handle bounces correctly.

The most practical way of setting the envelope sender is to copy it from the message's "from" address or to set it explicitly, and this is something that should be done by your contact form PHP code. If Contact Form 7 can be persuaded to use PHPMailer, it will happen automatically. If it sends directly via the mail function, or one of WordPress' wrappers it may be trickier, and you'd have to investigate further.

Anyway, just fixing the host name should get you an SPF `pass`, which is the immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, however this hasn't rectified the issue unfortunately.
The return path is still www-data@ubuntu
When I ran the hostname command, it didnt give me ubuntu but rather my servername. I ran the command you provided and updated it anyway

Comment: You may need to restart PHP or your web server for it to pick up the change. You can check the server environment it by running `var_dump($_SERVER);` in PHP.

Comment: I also facing this issue, mine always be Return-Path:  <www-data@mydomain.com> while I have  SPF:PASS , DKIM:PASS, DMARC:'PASS' and still ending up in Junk!

Anybody please help.

Comment: Failing to get a pass will often mean that you end up in a junk folder, however, having them all pass **does not** mean that you won't. There are many other factors that affect inbox placement, and most of them are unknown and outside your control. You might try reading [the PHPMailer docs on deliverability](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Improving-delivery-rates,-avoiding-spam-filters).